# Setup Javascript for HTML + CSS Menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

I would like to make the menu according to this style :- `http://www.australia.com/`

Here i made some changes, please look at the http://jsfiddle.net/fu3x6/

The menu should be slightly down the extended part.

Thanks

PPS

Comment: I may be wrong, but im pretty sure this site is used to solve specific problems you may be facing. It is not intended as a site where you can have all the hard work done for you. You may prefer to hire a web developer in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have not looked in to detail of the JS required, for each menu tab, and the HTML was required to change corresponding class in UL tag refer the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fu3x6/2/) for that

```
$('.ex').mouseover(function() {
 $('.extend').animate({"left": "250px"}, "slow");});
$('.ac').mouseover(function() {
 $('.extendac').animate({"left": "250px"}, "slow");});
$('.sp').mouseover(function() {
 $('.extendsp').animate({"left": "250px"}, "slow");});
$('.ma').mouseover(function() {
 $('.extendma').animate({"left": "250px"}, "slow");});
```

I have updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fu3x6/2/) for you here,

I hope this will do :) enjoy